Laravel File Upload with Nested Form-Data Returns Empty Files Array in Request [POSTMAN]
I’m working on a Laravel API that allows users to upload files as part of a nested form-data request. However, the files are not being detected properly in the request. Below is my current setup:
Request Structure:
The request is submitted as form-data using Postman. Here’s the structure:

skill_type (string): required
skill_description (string): required
portfolios (array): optional

Each portfolio includes:

description (string): optional

files (array of file uploads): optional


Laravel Form Request Validation Rules:
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'skill_type' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'skill_description' => 'required|string|max:2000',
        'portfolios' => 'nullable|array',
        'portfolios.*.files' => 'nullable|array',
        'portfolios.*.files.*' => 'file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf|max:2048',
    ];
}


Controller Logic:
public function register(StoreWorkerRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    return response()->json([
        'all_inputs' => $request->all(),
        'file_inputs' => $request->file('portfolios'),
    ]);
}

Files are attached as form-data in Postman, with the field names set as:

portfolios[0][files][] for the first file in the first portfolio, and
portfolios[1][files][] for the first file in the second portfolio.

Problem:
Despite attaching files correctly in Postman, the file_inputs response in Laravel shows empty arrays for files. The response looks like this:
{
    "all_inputs": {
        "skill_type": "Compete",
        "skill_description": "Insane designer",
        "portfolios": [
            {
                "description": "Portfolio 1 description",
                "files": [{}]
            },
            {
                "description": "Portfolio 2 description",
                "files": [{}]
            }
        ]
    },
    "file_inputs": [
        {
            "files": [{}]
        },
        {
            "files": [{}]
        }
    ]
}

What I’ve Tried:

Ensured the Content-Type header is not manually set in Postman (Postman automatically sets it to multipart/form-data).
Verified that files are being correctly attached in the form-data section of Postman.
Used $request->all() and $request->file() to inspect the inputs in Laravel.
As suggested by @C3roe I also dumped the $_FILE and I got the array of files selected in the postman as:

"file": {
       "portfolios": {
           "name": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       "c-sm.jpg"
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       "c-sm.jpg"
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "full_path": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       "c-sm.jpg"
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       "c-sm.jpg"
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "type": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       "image/jpeg"
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       "image/jpeg"
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "tmp_name": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\phpE252.tmp"
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\phpE253.tmp"
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "error": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       0
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       0
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "size": [
               {
                   "files": [
                       2701
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "files": [
                       2701
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   },

VALIDATION FOR THE FILES
'portfolios' => 'nullable|array',
 'portfolios.*.files' => 'nullable|array',
 'portfolios.*.files.*' => 'file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf|max:2048',

Expected Behavior: The file_inputs array should contain the uploaded file details (e.g., original_name, mime_type, size, etc.) for each attached file.
Question: Why are the files in my nested form-data request not being detected by Laravel, and how can I fix this to properly handle file uploads with a nested array structure?

What do you get when you dump $_FILES?

I got the array of uploaded files when I dumped $_FILES. I will edit my question and add the result now.

If $_FILES shows the uploaded files as expected (with a size, and no error), then most likely it is your validation setup, that makes them not available via the Laravel method. max:2048 - that's just 2KB, sure your files are smaller than that?

Can you inspect my validation. If the file size is less than 2048, shouldn't the validation throw a 422 ? I added the file validation rule to my OP

Your $_FILES dump says the size of both files was 2701, which is clearly not less than 2048.

If the file size is less than 2048, shouldn't the validation throw a 422...why do you expect that? Anyway, your validation rule is set to reject files which are bigger than 2048, not smaller. And your files as C3oe pointed out, are bigger than that limit.

I was going to say larger. @ADyson. my bad. Because I already had the validation max:2048 on the files. I assume it will throw a 422 when the size is larger than what what specified.

@DigitalBraine does the object you are trying to represent as json, ie. UploadedFile, have public properties or a serialization procedure?

if you check your output you are not getting an empty array, you are getting an array with an empty object [{}], meaning your file is represented as {}
